# How exactly does Pattern.matcher() work?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

So I'm trying to create a parser that will match certain parts of a string. String looks like f(q[group1],[group2])=(q[group3],[group4],[group5]). Pattern.matches() in code below returns true but I'm unable to access groups via matcher.group(int). Last line in code provided throws: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available

```
public class Parser {
   Pattern pattern;
   Matcher matcher;
   String g;

public Parser(String s) {
   g = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
   pattern = Pattern.compile("^f\\(q(\\d+),(.)\\)=\\(q([+-]*\\d+),(.),([+-])1\\)$");
   matcher = pattern.matcher(g);
   boolean b = Pattern.matches("^f\\(q(\\d+),(.)\\)=\\(q([+-]*\\d+),(.),([+-])1\\)$",g);

 System.out.println(b +   " ");
 System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
}
```

Comment: You're never matched anything against `matcher`. I'm not sure why you're calling the static method `Pattern.matches` but that line should read `boolean b = matcher.matches();`

Answer (score 0):

You're never matched anything against matcher. I'm not sure why you're calling the static method Pattern.matches but that line should read

```
boolean b = matcher.matches();
```

Like this:

```
public class Parser {
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    String g;

    public Parser(String s) {
        g = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        pattern = Pattern.compile("^f\\(q(\\d+),(.)\\)=\\(q([+-]*\\d+),(.),([+-])1\\)$");
        matcher = pattern.matcher(g);
        boolean b = matcher.matches();

        System.out.println(b + " ");
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the same thing and both return true. However, the main question is why I can't access groups via matcher.group(int)

Comment: You can access `matcher.group(int)` if you do `boolean b = matcher.matches();` first. You need to call `matches` or `find` first on the `Matcher` before you can access the `group` method.